# how to change cursor icon programmatically in c++

Tags: windows, winapi

I try to change cursor icon to another icon (from .cur or .ani file), i search for hours and try everything but cant solve this problem.

please help me by post a code or a taturial.

Answer (score 3):

You call [`SetCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393.aspx). You'll need to embed a cursor resource to your executable, load it with `LoadCursor`, and then pass that `HCURSOR` to `SetCursor`. If you want to be able to load a cursor from a file rather than embed it as a resource, use `LoadCursorFromFile`.

Comment: What says GetLastError() ?

Comment: GetLastError() return 2