# Where is loading circle on Windows stored at?

Tags: windows, operating-system

I am wondering where is, for example, that circle dotted loading animation stored, which we see on startup. What if I wanted a twerking amogus instead? IS it even possible to change that?

I'm not really looking for downloadable tools, I'm interested in deep understanding myself (I'm studying computer architecture at uni), so if you have any answer, it would make me super happy.

I changed sounds already, but it's apparently not enough for me. Also, is it possible to change a picture loaded in BIOS on the startup?

Edit: I don't mean changing the cursor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change cursor icon programmatically in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225183/how-to-change-cursor-icon-programmatically-in-c)

Comment: @ntg It is an interesting thing to do, but I was really speaking about the circle on startup. Thank you for help, but it's not the answer on my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

The Ring progressive animation appears to be able to be configured from the registry e.g.:
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-enable-new-progressive-ring-boot-animation-in-windows-11

> ```
> Open the Registry Editor.
> Navigate to SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control key
> Create a new key under the Control folder.
> Name it as BootControl.
> Create a new key (DWORD (32-bit.)
> Rename the new key as BootProgressAnimation.
> Change its value to 1.
> Restart your computer.
> ```

For changing the windows splash screen see e.g. here [Is it impossible to change the splash screen at runtime in uwp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278346/is-it-impossible-to-change-the-splash-screen-at-runtime-in-uwp)

The bios "splash" image is particular to your [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS). BIOS is basically a set of functions that are lower level than the OS and very hardware specific. So it is provided by the motherboard manufacturer. Depending on your motherboard you would have to Google on how to change it, most modern BIOS offer some option. The steps normally would be

- (good to do) update the BIOS firmware
- enter bios: involves pressing a key combination before booting the os, possibly del, or f1,... rtfm, or google your model
- go to option for selecting the splash screen and change it

It is possible that there is also an app from the manufacturer that can do that e.g. this is for asus: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-edit-an-asus-splash-screen

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this once I'm home. Still, thank you for your commitment!